# Mixing ObjectiveC and C++ causes either build error because header not found or linker error. How do I resolve the issue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If I name the file .mm and set the build configuration to Objective-C++ for the file, I see tons of linker errors for the Metal and Cocoa libs:

"_MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice", referenced from:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTKView", referenced from:

Etc...

If I switch it back to compiling as objective C, then the compile fails when it reaches an include for a C++ standard header file. I'm only including this because I tried it and didn't work, not because I want to mix C and C++.

I tried a number of things, here's some things I thought would work based upon previous SO posts:

I changed all the headers to compile as C++ instead of C-headers.

Under project settings -> Language -> Compile Sources As I set it to Objective-C++.

I looked through a number of SO posts and none of the solutions have thus worked.

Thank you for any help you can provide!